# Does reducing the size of mongodb documents reduce the working set?

Tags: mongodb, ram, working-set

I'm trying to determine if reducing the size of our documents will reduce our working set? Our database is reaching the limit of the RAM on our instances. We are storing redundant data in an array in each of our documents (can be thousands of elements), which I am now limiting to 40. That should reduce the size of the collection at fault to 10% of what it was (this is where our bulk is), but in my understanding of the documentation, storage size will not change. After reading up on mongo, I'm not sure if reducing document size to 10% of what they were originally will impact the working set? Can someone please help/explain?

**Edit: Some background information**

One of the things we've done to keep performance up as our database grows is to increase RAM to 'fit' the database in its entirety. The database is getting close to the 64GB of ram we have on our replica instances... That is what put this question forward...

**Edit: The essential question**

Essentially, the question comes down to this: **What should I use when I'm calculating if our working set fits in memory?** These numbers come from running db.stats():

dataSize + indexSize < RAM

OR

storageSize + indexSize < RAM

OR

fileSize + indexSize < RAM

Thanks!

Comment: It is good to note that reaching memory limit is not a bad thing. The working set is more of an active window of cached data that is used instead of the disk, think of how Postgres does it...it is similar. As to answer your question: maybe, it depends on whether that data is still needed

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the question with some background information. Is our logic sound? Is it a good idea to try to keep our DB within RAM size? It's hard to find a pattern of our data usage, but our data is seasonal (cleared once per year) and it is definitely not all in use all of the time.

Comment: Basically if that data can be kept out of working set and is not needed it will help, however, if it is needed as commonly as your working set of data in that collection then it could slow you down due to more queries